# why background process group die when terminal closed

Tags: session, terminal, nohup, sshd

According to this faq (and by many other books):

> ftp://rtfm.mit.edu/pub/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq
>
> 1.15 Why doesn't my process get SIGHUP when its parent dies?

SIGHUP won't be sent to background processes when none of them is  " *stopped* ".

but we all know that if SIGHUP isn't captured in background processes, they will die when you close the terminal(or connection like ssh).

**i.e. CTRL+Z - bg isn't enough for a process to survive when terminal is closed.**

But why?
Any wisdom is appreciated!

Comment: Background processes survive just fine when the terminal is closed.  They only terminate if they try to write to the closed terminal and receive SIGTTOU.

Comment: It would help if you clarified which shell you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy solution for it. Use nohup before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

After googling a bit.
I assume the HUP signal which result in exiting of background processes is from shell.

Here are the steps:

1. Terminal is closed, bash receives SIGHUP from kernel(driver)
2. Bash exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP. Before exiting, it resends the SIGHUP to **all jobs**, running or stopped
3. All jobs, including background processes, exit if they don't capture SIGHUP